# Uploading an attachment with Request

Tags: attachment, upload

I've been struggling with Salesforce's attachment upload API for a while, and having a hard time getting Request to format its request in a way that Salesforce is happy with. Here's what I'm working with so far:

```
  const request = require('request');
  const fs = require('fs');

  const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    uri: 'https://instance.salesforce.com/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/Attachment',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer token',
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    },
    multipart: [
      {
        'content-disposition': 'form-data',
        name: "entity_content",
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        body: JSON.stringify({
              "Name": "test",
              "Type": "text",
              "Description": "test",
              "Keywords": "test",
              "ParentId": "id",
        })
      },
      {
        'content-disposition': 'form-data',
        name: 'Body',
        filename: 'test.txt',
        'content-type': 'text/plain',
        body: fs.createReadStream('test.txt')
      }
    ]
  };

  const req = request(options, (err, httpResponse, body) => {
    if (err) {
      return console.error('upload failed:', err);
    }
    console.log('Server responded with:', body);
  })
```

At the moment, I'm getting "You have sent us an Illegal URL or an improperly formatted request." When I made a couple attempts using Request's multipart/form-data syntax rather than the multipart related, I had the slightly more helpful message "Multipart message must include a non-binary part," but my actual request looked farther from the example Salesforce gives in their docs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it turns out, just using the regular formData object with multiple keys was the way to go.

```
  const options = {
    url: 'https://instance.salesforce.com/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/Attachment',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer key',
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    },
    formData: {
      entity_document: {
        value: JSON.stringify({
            "Name": "test",
            "Description": "test",
            "ParentId": "id"
          }),
          options: {
            contentType: "application/json"
          }
        },
      Body: fs.createReadStream('./test.txt')
    }
  };

  request.post(options, (err, httpResponse, body) => {
    if (err) {
      return console.error('upload failed:', err);
    }
    console.log('Server responded with:', body);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this. I was struggling with the annoying error: `[{"message":"Multipart message must include a non-binary part","errorCode":"INVALID_MULTIPART_REQUEST"}]` because I couldn't figure out what it wanted from me. I used `request-promise` and this format works fine.